# Visual Studio won't build the ASP.NET Core project it created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

I've been doing asp.net core development for a few weeks without issue. This morning, I created a new ASP.NET core API web project. It generated the project, but when I tried to open it, it wouldn't open. I went to Add or Remove Programs and did opened up the installer with the intention to repair my VS 2017, but noticed there was a newer version, so I upgraded.

After the upgrade, it would open the project, but when it built, it wouldn't build. Did a repair of VS 2017, still wouldn't build. Repaired the asp.net core install, still didn't build. Uninstalled asp.net core and then reinstalled. Still didn't build.

There's a yellow warning icon on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (2.1.2)

I'm stumped. I get no message when it builds, other than:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: EmployeeDirectory, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Turning on diagnostic logging doesn't give me much more, except that it appears to be related to the dependency:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Running restore with 8 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file C:\Software Development\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory.csproj.
Restoring packages for C:\Software Development\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
Checking compatibility for EmployeeDirectory 1.0.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\Software Development\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\obj\project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\Software Development\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\obj\EmployeeDirectory.csproj.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 1.08 ms for C:\Software Development\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory.csproj.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\pd7562\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: EmployeeDirectory, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My version info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.8.8
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.8+28010.2048
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Professional

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.8.05085.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

 dotnet --list-sdks
 2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
 2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
 2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
 2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Nuget shows no packages installed. If I use the nuget manager to add the package, it seems to work, but my issue is never resolved:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design -Version 2.1.2
Restoring packages for C:\Software Development\Angular\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory.csproj...
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.2.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Software Development\Angular\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\obj\EmployeeDirectory.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Software Development\Angular\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 207.61 ms for C:\Software Development\Angular\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory\EmployeeDirectory.csproj.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.2' to EmployeeDirectory
Executing nuget actions took 246.18 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.5725993
```

Totally stumped... Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2017. Problem remains. I decided to create new kinds of projects and I'm now getting different errors. Tried to create Windows Forms app and I get the error:

`"Invalid static method invocation syntax: '[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToStandardLibraries($(TargetFrameworkIdentifier),$(TargetFrameworkVersion), $(TargetFrameworkProfile), $(PlatformTarget), $(TargetFrameworkRootPath), $(TargetFrameworkFallbackSearchPaths))'. Method 'Microsoft.Build.Utilitieis.ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToStandardLibraries' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()) e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine('a', 'b')). C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CurrentVersion.targets"`

**Update 2**

The package appears to be installed globally: in `C:\Users\[UserName]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.2`

Is it possible there's just a bad path or a missing environment variable that is causing this not to be found? Does anyone know how this is handled?

**Update 3**

```
dotnet --version
2.1.403
```

**Update 4**

I'm suspicious that my problem may have to do with this from the build log:

```
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\pd7562\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
```

When I go to the NuGet Package Manager/Package Sources in Tools/Options, for the "Machine-wide package", it shows only the "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" But my 2015 install show a "Microsoft and .NET" entry before that. These can't be edited, it doesn't look like.

I cleared out my packages directory under the user directory.nuget\packages and  it does not seem to be retrieving new packages into that directory. I think this is the fundamental issue that needs to be resolved. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Try to uninstall all .NET Core versions except 2.1.403 (you don't need those old ones anyway)

Comment: Done: dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Problem remains

Comment: Restart Visual Studio / computer after uninstalling the older .NET versions? :-)

Comment: Yes. Rebooted. No change.

Comment: I think the problem may be the nuget isn't actually installing the package. There's no package directory created. If I removed the package and then go to nuget to install it, it acts like it installed it just fine, but the "Install" button remains activated and I never get an uninstall option.

Comment: Just tried installing nhibernate in the project and it also acts like the install went fine, but then has the yellow warning icon and doesn't actually install the package.

Comment: The package appears to be in:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.2
Using procmon I see nuget is actually successfully looking in that folder. I'm still stumped.

Comment: Try to download NuGet again then

Comment: As best I can tell, the NuGet associated with Visual Studio is not separately installable.

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostic logging to see what exactly failed.

Comment: open up package management console (tools->nuget package manager->package manager console) and type "Update-Package -reinstall"

Comment: @LexLi I did. It's in the post above. It's just below the initial dump.

Comment: @Phill PM> Update-Package -reinstall
No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'EmployeeDirectory'.

Comment: Completely uninstalled VS 2017 and then reinstalled it. The problem remains.

Comment: You enabled nothing at all. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/

Comment: @LexLi I enabled Diagnostic for "MSBuild project build output verbosity" as well as "MSBuild project build log verbosity", which is the output displayed in the section right after the minimal build verbosity, which begins with: "Restoring NuGet packages...", hence the more detailed messages.

Comment: Can you run `dotnet --version` and `dotnet build -v d` at the project directory and paste the output as part of question?

Comment: @LexLi I addded the dotnet -version output. The build succeeded with dotnet build command. The verbose output was too much to post here. Far more than what's showing up in the Visual Studio build, but more akin to the normal diagnostic output I'd expect. The output of the build is 2MB.

Comment: Unfortunately, that truly indicates a Visual Studio issue, as `dotnet` command can successfully compile your code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzszcehe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Report to Microsoft. In the worst case, you have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Is this project in source control? If yes, please check if any `\packages` add to the source control, if yes, move it out. And try to uninstall that package and reinstall it manually. The worst way is to manually download the package and directly add the dll files in the package to the project. You need to provide a log of the failed build, which should help us to find the reason, and  don't need a full log, just the part that failed.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT No. I create the project from scratch, so it's the empty template asp.net core API project. It won't build. There is no "packages" directory.
The full diagnostic log is up there for you to see. It's quite short. It's indicative of the build issue I'm having. it begins with "Restoring NuGet packages" and ends with "========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========" I get that it doesn't LOOK like a full diagnostic log, but it's all I get for a full diagnostic log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a similar issue cropped up back in the release of 15.8.0 and the same fix that worked for that glitch worked for me. The problem was caused by a Visual Studio update in both cases.

I found the solution here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311136/update-to-1580-projects-wont-load.html

The solution was to exit Visual Studio and run the following from the Developer Command Prompt:

```
gacutil /u "MSBuild, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Engine, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0"
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0"
```

On my system the first 2 didn't do anything, but the other 6 uninstalled the appropriate stuff from the GAC. I include the first 2 for completeness, however.

When I restarted Visual Studio, it said it was setting stuff up as if it were the first time I had run it since installation.

I'm now able to build my ASP.NET core projects as well as being able to generate and open other project types that were causing me problems.

Hope this helps someone else.